# how do I activate my jquery tabber based on the link URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to jquery and I decided to build a jquery tabber. So far so good but I have a little problem!!! I cant see how I can activate the tabber based on the URL. For instance when the link is `www.myweb.com#tab2`, the second tabber becomes activated. My jquery is as follows.  Now I know jquery has it's own tabber script but I don't want to use it. So anybody else help me accomplish this please

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var hash = location.hash;
    var link1 = ("ul#tabs li a[href='" + hash + "']")
    var link2 = ("ul.tabs li a[href='" + hash + "']")
    var link3 = ("ul#tabs li[href='" + hash + "']")

    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    if ((link3.length)(link2.length)(link1.length))

            { //check if such link exists
                      $(link3, link2, link1).parent().addClass("active"); //Activate tab
                      $(hash).show();
    }

    else {
      $("ul.tabs li a:first, ul#tabs li:first, ul#tabs li a:first").addClass('active');
      $(".tab_content:first").show()

        // On Click Event
        $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
            $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
            $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
            $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

            var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
            $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
            return false;
        });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Design Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Publications</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Awards &amp; Recognitions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4">Our Mission</a></li>
    <li class="last-item"><a href="#tab1">Company Profile</a></li>
</ul>
```

this is how far I have come. Since I have 3 selectors the jquery code is weirdly not working how do I achieve this so tabber is activated based on URL? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at JQueryUI, they have pre-built components like this.
Specifically: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

**Edit:**

Or is their a specific reason why you are building your own?

Comment: yes I have used it in all my pages and I don't want to do that whole editing again

Answer (score 0):

You can set the selected tab using the  following :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#tabs').tabs(); // make jquery tabs

    $("#tabs").tabs("select", window.location.hash);
});
```

Second parameter of `$.tabs` function accept either index or a selector.